# Emacs Lisp-error meaning when trying (require 'package)

Tags: emacs, package, emacs23

I have an `init.el` file which only consists of a single line

```
(require 'package)
```

I am running `emacs 23.1` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server Release 6.10 (Santiago)

[image: Red Hat]

Execution of `emacs --debug-init` returns the following screen:

[image: Error]

I have absolutely no clue as to what this means.

This was actually a **very** preliminary step to following the [instructions](https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) on setting up `elpy` as IDE for `python`... After I had no success in using the standard mode with `python3` instead of just `python`

Could it be that these machines cannot access the internet?

Comment: Please post your question about using elpy etc. separately. Only one question per post, please.

Comment: I believe that to achieve your end-goal you will need to update to a newer version of Emacs than 23.1.  I suggest using the latest stable release, which is 27.2.

Comment: Hey Drew, can you show me where I did ask anything about `elpy`?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`package.el` is not part of Emacs 23.  You can obtain it [here](https://github.com/technomancy/package.el), I believe. (That's
`https://github.com/technomancy/package.el`.)

No idea whether that version of the library is compatible out of the box with Emacs 23.

But you get the idea - search for `package.el` online, download it, and put it in your `load-path`. Then your `require` should pick it up.

Comment: I *suspect* that a bigger problem will be that `elpy` (or its dependencies) will very likely not support Emacs 23, which is at this point very old.  I'm not sure the regular package archives even work with versions of `package.el` pre-dating its inclusion in Emacs... I have a recollection that there was a separate archive for the older version, and I imagine it hasn't been touched in years.

Comment: I'll go beyond etiquette here and just thank you, this is a machine I have zero control over, but it is good to know that these packages are probably not supported and the `emacs` version rather old. It gives me leverage to ask for an update.

Comment: While you are updating emacs, you might ask about an update to the OS as well: RHEL 6.10  will happily run recent emacs I think, but it *is* old and [no longer supported](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4768501?tour=8).